# pgr_nodeNetwork doesn't place new nodes properly

Tags: postgis, vector, pgrouting, intersection

I wanted to use pgr_nodeNetwork tool to split lines where there's no vertex on intersection. The tool doesn't seem to work as expected, though. It doesn't place new nodes right where the two lines cross. Tolerance value doesn't affect the result. In the first attached image you can see original location of nodes and in the second one you can see the result of pgr_nodeNetwork function. This is pgrouting version 2.0 with PostGIS 2.2.0. Any ideas?
[image: original node layout]

[image: nodes resulting from pgr_nodeNetwork function]

Comment: Can you provide the query you are using and also a link to the data (or data sample on area).  We are working on pgr_NodeNetwork for pgRouting 2.2.